# opening a child window in silverlight by using .aspx file from the web project

Tags: asp.net, silverlight, telerik, prism

I am new to silverlight and asp.net, we are using silverlight and prism framework,
I have a main page designed in the .apsx page with the help of web controls (.ascx) and web pages(.aspx). I want to have a login page (which comes with the business application in silverlight like a child window), my question is, is there any way we can call the child window designed in silverlight project by writing the code in .aspx page ?

by using a hyperlink button in .aspx page and calling the login window in the silverlight page.
cause in this project the mainpage is designed in .aspx page.